# How to get statusCode from Axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, axios

When I `axios` dump in NodeJS the response I get

```
 res:
  IncomingMessage {
    _readableState: [ReadableState],
    readable: false,
    _events: [Object],
    _eventsCount: 3,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    socket: [TLSSocket],
    connection: [TLSSocket],
    httpVersionMajor: 1,
    httpVersionMinor: 1,
    httpVersion: '1.1',
    complete: true,
    headers: [Object],
    rawHeaders: [Array],
    trailers: {},
    rawTrailers: [],
    aborted: false,
    upgrade: false,
    url: '',
    method: null,
    statusCode: 201,            <----------
    statusMessage: 'Created',
    client: [TLSSocket],
    _consuming: false,
    _dumped: false,
    req: [Circular],
    responseUrl:
     'https://example.com/',
    redirects: [] },
```

and would really like to get the `statusCode`.

If I do

```
console.log(response.headers.status)
console.log(response.headers.location)
console.log(response.statusText)
console.log(response.statusCode)
```

then I get

```
200
https://example.com/
Created
undefined
```

So I get get the `200` status code from `response.headers`, but I also want to get the `201` status code.

## Question

Can anyone show me how I get extract the `statusCode` that in this case is `201`?

Comment: try `console.log(response.status)` instead of  `console.log(response.statusCode)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's very easy to get it:

```
axios
  .get(url)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.status);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error({ error });
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `async` `await`:

```
const fetchData = async (url) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url);

    console.log("status code:", response.status);
    console.log("status text:", response.statusText);
    console.log("data:", response.data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Axios error: ", err);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
axios
 .get(url)
 .then((response) => {
  console.log(response.headers.status)
  console.log(response.headers.location)
  console.log(response.statusText)
  console.log(response.status) //change statusCode to status,
 })
```

try this,